# Listen for changes in Formik field using ref and useEffect

Tags: reactjs, formik

I'm trying to use the `ref` in Formik to let `useEffect` listen for changes in form field values. But when I run:

```
const formikRef = useRef(); // this gets passed to Formik's ref prop on component render

React.useEffect(() => {
    // do something
}, [formikRef.current.state.values.MyFormFieldName]);
```

It fails with this error: `Cannot read property 'state' of undefined`

I'm on Formik v1.3 and I can't directly access the Field component since I'm using a custom wrapper component (as part of an internal UI library) and it doesn't expose all the Field props.

EDIT:

I can do `formikRef.current?.state.values.MyFormFieldName` but that still doesn't cause useEffect to fire when `MyFormFieldName` changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error because when the component initializes, the `current` property is `null / undefined` and you are trying to access a property (`state`) of it.

In addition, passing the hook to the dependency array seems to have not the effect you desire, in short it seems to have [no effect](https://medium.com/tech-eatwith/how-to-use-react-refs-with-useeffect-hooks-9a0b31a7b398):

> React Hook useEffect has an unnecessary dependency: ‘formikRef.current’. Either exclude it or remove the dependency array. Mutable values like ‘contentRef.current’ aren’t valid dependencies because mutating them doesn’t re-render the component

A workaround for your problem (described at the end of the previously linked article) would be to save the ref in the state after initialization:

```
const App = (props) => {
  const [formik, setFormik] = React.useState();

  const formikRef = (node) => {
    if (node !== null) {
      setFormik(node.getBoundingClientRect().height);
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // do something
  }, [formik]);

  return (
    <div ref={formikRef}>
      <span>Hello Bro</span>
    </div>
  );
};
```

You can play with the example on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Gh05d/pen/RwaEJrN?editors=1011).